# Invalid token format google people

Tags: php, symfony, google-api, google-oauth, google-people-api

I use google api people for view google contact in php.

I took this example https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/simple-file-upload.php and an api quickstart.php

I have the error message : "Invalid token format", I use symfony.

I followed well the github documentation but is not running

here is this line

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
}


if (isset($_GET['code'])) {

  $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
  $client->setAccessToken($token);

  // store in the session also
  $_SESSION['upload_token'] = $token;

  // redirect back to the example
  header('Location: ' . filter_var('http://localhost:8000/', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}


if (!empty($_SESSION['upload_token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  }
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}
```

Comment: can you include the full error message? The error should point out where do we look first or what's the cause of the issue.

Comment: As you use the Symfony tag I suppose you are using the Symfony Framework and not only some components. Did you read the docs about how Symfony handle Session? (and also about the Request part)

Answer (score 0):

can you try first to start the session in the above of the document by typing :

```
session_start();
```

and you need to add between 5 and 6 line the following code to test that $token is an array with an access_token key and not and error key.

```
if ($token['error']) {
        error_log("$token[error]: $token[error_description]");
    }
```

i hope you found this answer helpful and i will leave some links below i hope you check them and if you had problems let me know

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/1496

Comment: I had already put a session_start(), that when I arrive if on the page, if I refresh it the invalid token error appears

Comment: you don't need to use session_start() if you are using the Symfony framework

Comment: if I don't put a session_start i have this error message                                         
 "error": {
"code": 401,
"message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
"errors": [
{
"message": "Login Required.",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "required",
"location": "Authorization",
"locationType": "header"